# How to apply a non default H1 only for a specific category?

Tags: magento2

I need to change the H1 only for one specific category.
The default in Magento 2 is that it will be the category name and I need it to be different in one category.

Comment: I don't understand your problem, what you need to change? Styling of <h1> or Content ?

Comment: Content of H1, but only for a specific category

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a simple way how to do it from admin panel.

1. Admin -> Catalog -> Categories
2. Pick desired category
3. Go to "Search Engine Optimization" section -> fill meta title with the title  you want to have

Now...

```
This will change 2 things
```

- category title on the page
- meta title

Hope this helps you if you want a solution without changing the meta title there will be some coding to do, please respond and I can find a solution for you :)

Comment: It's not working. The Meta title is already different and it is only reflected on the meta title.
I thought that there can be a solution that relates to:
Category -> Design ->  Layout Update XML,
On the specific category I need to change the H1 content for

Comment: Strange I wonder why it is working on my 2.3.3 com instance, thou I'm trying to make it work on some demo instance, and it is not working o.o
I was trying to update it via xml but it didn't work 
Well I got busy next 3 days... will check this out on Monday on a fresh instance.